# No overload for method 'Export_ex' takes '1' arguments error when calling a webservice in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

i have write a web service  in asp .net c# when i call it from java script i get the error No overload for method 'Export_ex' takes '1' arguments when calling a webservice.

here is javascript code

```
function myF() {

        var data = demo.innerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/Export_ex",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
            var show = response.d;
                alert(show);
               // alert("success");


            },
            failure: function(msg) {
                alert("Error occur, could not load the service.");
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is my webservice method

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void Export_ex(string elem)
        {
            string elements = "elem";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Print.xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<head>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<div>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-     8\">");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:Name>Report Data</x:Name>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:Print>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</xml>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</head>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(elements);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); ;

        }
```

can anyone help?

Comment: you have to pass argument while you call your service

Comment: @DhavalPatel: he does: `data: ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should not `stringify` your data. (It will be serialized along the way):

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Should be:

```
data : data
```